# ZSH alias run command based on condition

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I want to create an alias that invokes the fzf command and cd's into the directory. If the selected path is a file, it should just cd into the file's parent directory.

I created this:

```bash
alias fcf='if [[ -f $(fzf) ]]; then cd `dirname $(fzf)`; else cd $(fzf);'
```

`$(fzf)` is the path. For some reason it's not working. I always get `cd: not a directory:`. Any hints?

Comment: I'm not sure if aliases support chained commands like `if else`; but even if they do it would be better to use a function instead: `fcf() { if ...; then ...; else ...; fi; }`. Note the `fi` at the end. I think it is missing in your alias.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `bash`?

Comment: The (BTW obsolete) backquotes are not evaluated inside single quotes. Aside from this, using an _alias_ for this type of task is IMO a poor choice. Why do you insist in having an alias for this?

Comment: I don't insist. Function is the better choice.

Comment: Don't you only want to run `fzf` once, and use the same result for both the `-f` test and the command to execute later?

Comment: @chepner Yes, you're right. I'd have to introduce a variable.

Comment: Not really clear if this would fix your problem, but I'd write something like `fcf () { p=$(fzf); [[ -f $p ]] && p=$p:h; cd "$p"; }`.

Comment: You could try `alias fcf='test -d "$(fzf)" || : $_:h; cd -- $_'` if you'd really like an alias

Comment: @rowboat Thank you very much. This works great. Do you want to add it as an answer?